# Firefox tab titles not visible in Radiance theme

Tags: unity, firefox, radiance

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

I changed my theme to **Radiance** and now I cannot see tab titles in Firefox browser.

[image: screenshot, tab title area shows blank]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you using a custom style with stylish or userChrome.css?

Comment: No, I am not using any custom style.

Comment: Bug reports and problems with the development version of Ubuntu should be [reported on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More Firefox's fault than Ubuntu's as now in version 29 unselected tabs are completely transparent. You can use the brilliant [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) extension to get it back to looking like older versions, or simply make unselected tabs visible.

Here's what it looks like normally in Firefox 29 with the Radiance theme <sub>*(I don't have the problem though)*</sub>:

[image: Radiance theme, normal]

Here's what I have with Classic Theme Restorer and it set to 'Curved Tabs (Alternative)'

[image: Radiance theme, Curved Tabs (Alternative)]

You can also set it to do the old style square tabs, small icons etc:

[image: square tabs]